# How to execute one of two queries based on a condition in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to execute one of two queries based on a condition?
Pseudo code example:

```
IF condition
    SELECT a,b,c FROM table1
ELSE
    SELECT d,e,f FROM table2
```

P.S. I know I can do the condition in my server code, but I'm looking for a pure Mysql solution.

Comment: You can only do this in a stored procedure.

Comment: [Working with Stored Procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) to accomplish this in pure MySQL, since the [if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) statement is only available in [compound statement syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html), which is in turn only available in stored programs (procedures, functions triggers). As you want to execute `select` statements, you can only use a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE yourproc()
BEGIN
    IF condition THEN
        SELECT a,b,c FROM table1;
    ELSE
        SELECT d,e,f FROM table2;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

You will call the stored proc from your code:

```
CALL yourproc();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found another solution. Probably less economic, but since I'm using small tables for an offline process it doesn't much matter. The plus for me is that it don't require a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c, 'Q_1' AS origin_query FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d, e, f, 'Q_2' AS origin_query FROM table2
) temp
WHERE origin_query = IF (condition, 'Q_1', 'Q_2');
```